# Need help understanding the meaning of "latest push"

Tags: meaning

The sentence is:

> A year and a half later and the company is still at it, with the 15 proposed stores being its *latest push*.

([www.eater.com](http://www.eater.com/a/starbucks-income-map))

Does this sentence mean that 15 restaurants will be opened soon, or that they are almost built, or *what*? I could only find the phrase *"final push"* in the dictionary.

Comment: It only means they are in the proposal stage. Many things could go wrong with one or more of their newly proposed locations. However, "still at it" implies the company has a successful record of adding stores, adding confidence that they will follow through with their plans. Starbucks certainly has the resources to build them, but they could fail due to external forces like a city council zoning issue or a bad deal with the landlord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the company is planning to open the restaurants and is actively working on this project.

It's not clear when this will happen, but they are working towards opening 15 new stores in lower-income inner-city neighborhoods and have already selected cities and locations.

Regarding "push":

> push: A vigorous or **insistent effort** toward an end; a drive:
>   *a push to reform health care.*

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=push))